# Remove "Category:"

Tags: categories, filters

I would like to remove "Category:" from "Category: Scotland" for example. I have tried with below:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                        add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {

if ( is_category() ) {

        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

        $title = single_tag_title( '', false );

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {

        $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;

    }

return $title;

});
```

But this also removes "Scotland". How do I solve this (same goes for tags and author)?

Original `archive.php` - located in: `wp-content\themes\islemag\archive.php`

```
get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="islemag-content-left col-md-9">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php 

                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                    endwhile; 

                    the_posts_navigation(); 

                else : 

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); 

                endif; 
        ?>
    </div><!-- End .islemag-content-left -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- End .row -->
```

Comment: Your code looks like a mix between a template (where your loop is) and the functions file (where you define your filters). Are you sure this is what you are using? In any case `$title` is not echoed in this code, so no wonder nothing is shown.

Comment: See my original archive.php file above (edited).

Answer (score 0):

After your edit it makes more sense. First, you should really [read up on filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). They exist to modify the behaviour of functions. They are included in `functions.php`.

So if you use the function `the_archive_title` it contains a filter [`get_the_archive_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/) to modify its output. It looks like you got your code snippet from that developer page, actually, but put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok - could you help me place it correctly? Or purhaps modify the code if necessary?

Comment: You don't have to do anything with the original `archive.php`. The complete snippet you found goes in `functions.php`. Just put it right before the closing `?>` tag.

Comment: Didn't seem to work - I might have done it wrong.